# Canonical answer for "Why not authenticate with the user sending an SMS?" should have its duplicate tags swapped

Tags: discussion, status-completed, exact-duplicates

There are a number of questions on this site asking essentially the same question:

> Why do 2FA apps send an SMS to the user rather than have the user send an SMS to the server?

here are some examples:

1. [3 votes] [SMS Verification Code vs. Response Message](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/199573/61443). Top answer: 3 votes. Flagged as possible duplicate of (2).
2. [25 votes] [Why do apps with phone verification send the user a message, rather than have the user send one to them?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/193904/61443). Top answer: 80 votes. Flagged as duplicate of (3).
3. [3 votes] [Why not authenticate with the user sending an SMS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/185543/61443). Top answer: 3 votes. Flagged as possible duplicate of (2), but vote looks like it failed.

It seems weird that a post with 25 / 80 upvotes is marked as a duplicate and pointing to a post with 3/3 votes.

**Moderators: Can we flip the dupe flag so that (3) points to (2) ?**

(Thanks to @AndrolGenhald for pointing this out)

Comment: I don't think vote count is the relevant factor here, but quality and generality.

Comment: The HMQ title snippet made it sound like you wanted an argument against SMS as a second factor... [here might be one for that purpose](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/158783/149193).